# Effects for Jokosher

Tags: music, sound

I've installed Jokosher and all the LADSPA effects I could see, but when I try to add an effect to a track Jokosher says none are installed.

Do I need some extra Gstreamer package to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad package to get LADSPA support within GStreamer.

Cheers,
 Mike.

Comment: That got me the effects. Unfortunately I can't seem to play or record anything. Jokosher just locks up. This question may still be useful to others